# How to get a question reopened?

Tags: discussion

I have this question here, "[Internment Camp for Magical Creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/158065/internment-camp-for-magical-beings)" which was put on hold - and looking back I can see why. Since it was put on hold I have edited it, added details and made it much more clear - and someone even upvoted it. How do I get "the hold" removed"?

And more generally, what is the process for "removing holds" and "reopening closed questions".

Comment: A good place to start would be reading up about the close vote process in the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: Read that, and I followed the instructions from the people commenting on it. It was closed for being too broad, I narrowed it down and was wondering what the next steps are ... In both this instance and generally...

Comment: The link which sphennings gave you lead to: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions), It suggests how you might write an explanatory comment on your own question as to why it should be re-opened then it goes into a little explanation of review queues. It's just a question of democracy from then on.

Comment: Yes, I saw that - and I have edited the question, added details (both as requested from comments and more as I felt they were important).

Comment: You may not be aware of the recent upheavals with the whole network, but they may have lead *temporarily* to fewer people looking at review queues, and [fewer mods on duty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334575/dear-stack-exchange-a-statement-and-a-letter-from-your-moderators). Normal service may be resumed shortly, we hope.

Comment: I have never had a question placed on hold - so I don't know what normal or slower than normal would be. I am aware about the "gong-show" that started with Monica's termination and quickly went out of control on SE side of things...I was just curious about the procedure from here...Thanks

Comment: Maybe mods could give you a statistical breakdown using their tools (maybe, I'm not a mod), but from what I've seen as a rule of thumb, a day (24 hours) on a weekday or the full 48+ hours on a week-end as at weekends users tend to be less active on the site. However, at the moment, it's anyone's guess.

Comment: @Crosbonaught as of now that question has three reopen votes. Two more and it'll get reopened.

Answer (score 4):

Getting your question re-opened is going to end up being a popularity contest while having to confirm to the rules of this Stack Exchange.

So your question is closed, you've made the edits and want to get it reopened. The magical number is 5 reopened votes, and getting those votes is hard.

First thing is that make an edit will move it to the top of the Active page. Here users who are interested in your question, can go in, have a read and vote to re-open it. If you have a popular question that happens to attract the attention of many people, it gets reopened faster. People see your question. Read it and vote to re-open if they want to. To this end, having easy to read, well formatted and shorter questions will likely get opened faster, because it wont take as much effort to get through everything.

The second way is through the review queue. There are several queues for users with a lot of points which make it easier to users to moderate questions and answers here. Your question will be placed in the re-open queue and any people who are reviewing will see it there as well. To that end, you still need to have a well formatted question because lets me honest. If you see a wall of text you might just skip the review and leave it to the next person.

Finally, I believe Moderators can open a question which was unfairly closed. This can happen sometimes, but usually happens the other way when someone asks a clearly inappropriate question and a Mod closes it straight away. This is going to be rare, and sometimes, bringing it to the attention of meta can help get the required attention to open your question. However do not expect this to happen.

Comment: I concur: even though you've edited it (reasonably satisfactorily), it could stand to be pruned a little more, perhaps.  It's certainly a skill, learning how to balance information required for understanding and writing just enough question to get a good answer.